# Flask and SQLAlchemy in a Declarative setup - how to change the database engine or connection for testing?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

In short the problem is I followed the Flask docs to set up SQLAlchemy in a declarative way. This example has the connection string as a fixed value, and I can't find examples on how to set up the database connection dynamically from a connection string in a config file.

Following the example in the [Flask docs here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/patterns/sqlalchemy/#declarative), I now have a `database\__init__.py` with the following contents:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker, declarative_base
from config import Config

engine = create_engine(Config.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, echo=Config.SQLALCHEMY_ECHO)
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                         autoflush=False,
                                         bind=engine))
Base = declarative_base()
Base.query = db_session.query_property()


def init_db():
    from trial.database import models
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

Now if I want to change the `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL` in my tests, I can't override them, because they are imported from my CONFIG file.
I can of course, add an override class `TestConfig()` to my config file, and use that in my conftest.py, like so:

```
from myapp ingimport create_app
from config import TestingConfig
from trial import database


@pytest.fixture()
def app():
    app = create_app(config_class=TestingConfig)

    with app.app_context():
        database.init_db()

    yield app

    # put teardown code here


@pytest.fixture()
def client(app):
    return app.test_client()
```

But that doesn't solve my problem, because the `database\__init__.py` file will still import  the regular `Config` and not the `TestingConfig`. I can't change that because my production application imports this file.

I can't find an example online where creating and configuring the database and engine is done in a loosely coupled function or passed in in some way. I figure that that would be a solution.

Currently in different places in my code `Base` and `db_session` are imported directly from `database`, so my code depends on these objects being available in the import.

The thing is this is (one of the) way(s) that it's documented in the Flask docs, but I can't find a decent example online on how to use this way of setting up SQLAlchemy in combination PyTest, using a different database for testing. If anyone can provide such an example, I would be very happy.